# How to capture a String expression and replace only a part of it?

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I would like to capture the following String expressions:

Matches:

```
 - MyUtilClass.cast(MyClass.class, <-- including the space after comma
 - MyUtilClass.cast(MyClass2.class, <-- including the space after comma
 - MyUtilClass.cast(MyClass3.class, <-- including the space after comma
```

And replace matches with:

```
 - MyUtilClass.uncheckedCast(
 - MyUtilClass.uncheckedCast(
 - MyUtilClass.uncheckedCast(
```

Results:

```
- MyUtilClass.uncheckedCast(query.getResultList());
- MyUtilClass.uncheckedCast(q.getResultList());
- MyUtilClass.uncheckedCast(rootQuery.getResultList());
```

I am using Eclipse IDE.

Thank you

Comment: Are the classes actually called `MyClass`, `MyClass2` and `MyClass3`? Or is it possible that there can be any class names?

Comment: Actually it's any class names, like Target.class, User.class, Region.class, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
MyUtilClass[.]cast[(]MyClass\d*[.]class,\s*
```

or if you have only `MyClass, MyClass2 and MyClass3` use the following

```
MyUtilClass[.]cast[(]MyClass[23]?[.]class,\s*
```

And replace with the following:

```
MyUtilClass.uncheckedCast(
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mH1wT4/1)

Answer (score 1):

REGEX:

```
- MyUtilClass\.cast\(MyClass[23]?\.class,\s*
```

Replace with:

```
- MyUtilClass.uncheckedCast(
```

Comment: `[23]?` should be after `MyClass` :)

Answer (score 0):

This matches `"MyUtilClass.cast(AnyClassName.class, "` and replaces it with `"MyUtilClass.uncheckedCast("`:

```
String regex = Pattern.quote("MyUtilClass.cast(") + "[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\\d_$]*"
        + Pattern.quote(".class, ");

s = s.replaceAll(regex, "MyUtilClass.uncheckedCast(");
```